# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Panel'

Tags: python, pandas, panel, statsmodels, attributeerror

I'm working on a Time Series project and want to use the statsmodels package. However I'm having trouble to import it.
When I run this : `import statsmodels.api as sm`

I get this error : `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Panel'`

I saw in an other topic that the panel has been removed from Pandas module 0.25.0 onwards. Is there a way I can still use the statsmodels package in the version 1.2.3 of Pandas ?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably upgrade `statsmodels` package. `import statsmodels.api as sm` runs without error on my system.

Comment: Thank you that was it !